# I am not able to perform operations after getting connected to sqlite.It immediately disconnects

Tags: java, sqlite

I am new to sqlite.I am getting the output as shown below.how to provide input through sqlite.Should i go through cmd?Please help me out.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

class TelephoneList{
//code

 public static void main( String args[] ) {
      try {
          Connection c;
          PreparedStatement stmt;
          Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
          c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:TelephoneList.db");
          System.out.println("----------Connected to Database successfully----------");
          System.out.println();
          String createTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TelephoneList (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Person NVARCHAR(100), Telephone NVARCHAR(50))";
          stmt = c.prepareStatement(createTable);
          stmt.executeUpdate();
          TelephoneList tl = new TelephoneList();
          if(args.length < 1) {
            tl.printHelpScreen();
          }
          else if(args[0].equals("ADD")){
              if(args.length != 3){
                  tl.printHelpScreen();
              }
              else{
                  tl.add(args[1], args[2], c);
              }
          }
          else if(args[0].equals("DEL")){
              if(args.length != 2){
                  tl.printHelpScreen();
              }
              else{
                      if(validatePhone(args[1])){
                          tl.deleteTelephone(args[1], c);
                      }
                      else if(validateName(args[1])){
                          tl.deletePerson(args[1], c);
                      }
                      else{
                          System.err.println("Invalid Person Name or Telephone");
                          System.exit(1);
                      }
              }
          }
          else if(args[0].equals("LIST")){
              if(args.length != 1){
                  tl.printHelpScreen();
              }
              else{
                  tl.list(c);
              }
          }
          else{
              tl.printHelpScreen();
          }
          stmt.close();
          System.out.println("----------Disconnected from Database----------");
          c.close();
          System.exit(0);
      }
      catch ( Exception e ) {
          System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
          System.exit(0);
      }
}
}
```

The output is:

```
----------Connected to Database successfully----------

Please provide any of the below arguments in correct format to proceed with any operation
ADD "<Person>" "<Telephone #>"
DEL "<Person>"
DEL "<Telephone #>"
LIST
----------Disconnected from Database----------
```

I am just able to see the above output.I am not able to provide any sort of input.I have installed the sqlite jar file in my project also.I tried through cmd prompt also.But after compiling javac filename.java ,nothing happens.

Comment: Are you trying to pass input to your program through command line arguments, or interactive input? Your program is looking at `args`, which are the command line arguments.

Comment: You also have to tell us how you're trying to invoke your program (specifically, what command line args are you passing). It could well be that the program is working as intended, but your expectations of how it should work are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your are not passing arguments to your app when executing it.
try to do something like `System.out.println(args.length)` to check if the arguments are passed or there is something wrong.
basically, if you are running code from an IDE, you have to modify the IDE to pass the arguments

Comment: I want to run through cmd,but after i give javac TelephoneList.java nothing appears.

Comment: Can you provide the cmd line you use. please.